# Using gulp-zip to compress main directory and exclude sub-directory

Tags: gulp, gulp-zip

I am using gulp-zip to zip up my source files. I need to assign gulp.src to compress all main directory contents excluding sub-directory "node_modules"

I tried this

```
/* Zip task */
gulp.task('zip', function() {
  return gulp
    .src(['./**', '!node_modules/**'])
    .pipe(zip('archive.zip'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('zip'))
});
```

I got archived .zip files with the excluded directory !node_modules with empty content. However, I`d like to find any way to not include that directory in the archive even when being empty.

Answer (score 2):

```
gulp.src([
'**/*',
'!node_modules/**'
])
```